# Manually computing bootstrap standard errors in the linear regression setting

Tags: r, bootstrap, standard-error

I have written an R script for obtaining bootstrapped standard errors in the linear regression setting.

In practice, first in a model building step I select the final model to be applied at each bootstrapped sample (for simplicity suppose that it is a simple univariate linear model).

Then I simulate `B = 1000` bootstrap samples (with replacement from the initial true dataset). For each simulated sample I fit the initially defined univariate regression model to the simulated data and store the estimated coefficient of the covariate of interest in `b_x`.

Suppose now for simplicity that `B = 10`. At the end of the `B` simulations, I obtain the output matrix `boot_out` in this form:

```
boot_out <- read.table(text = "

iter      b_x
    1       1.19
    2       0.81
    3       1.21
    4       1.05
    5       0.99
    6       1.11
    7       1.09
    8       0.88
    9       0.91
    10      1.12",

header=TRUE)
```

Now I need to compute the bootstrapped standard error of the effect of the regressor of interest, call it `se_boot`.

To this aim, I used:

```
se_boot <- sd(boot_out[,"b_x"])
se_boot
```

but I get a unexpected result: the bootstrapped standard error of `b_x` is **higher** than the standard error estimated through the initial model fitted to the true data..

By looking at my `b_x` values I found that the estimates of the partial effect of interest vary within a wide range, but I guessed that 1000 bootstrap replications were sufficient for refining the estimated standard error of `b_x`..

Before trying to do even more replications, could you please tell me whether the above passages are right?

Thanks a lot for any help.